# Retrieving a substring from an exponentially growing string

Tags: python

For integer A, the base level of 1 is "XYZ"
For subsequent levels, the levels become "X" + Level (A - 1) + "Y" + Level (A - 1) + "Z".
So for level 2, the string would be "XXYZYXYZZ"

The objective is to return the substring from the Level string using the Start and End Index.

Example: If entering 2 3 7, it would Level 2, 3rd character to the 7th character and the result would be "YZYXY" from "XXYZYXYZZ"

The following constraints are given:

- 1 ≦ Level K ≦ 50,
- 1 ≦ start ≦ end ≦ length of Level K String,
- 1 ≦ end - start + 1 ≦ 100.

I have written a brute force approach for this problem in Python as follows

```
def my_substring():
    level = int(input())
    start_index = int(input()) - 1
    end_index = int(input())
    strings_list = [None] * level
    strings_list[0] = "XYZ"

    for i in range(1, level):
        strings_list[i] = "X" + strings_list[i - 1] + "Y" + strings_list[i - 1] + "Z"

    return "".join(strings_list[-1])[start_index:end_index]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(my_substring())
```

As shown, the length of the string will increase by (base string * 2) + 3 for each iteration.  Past the 20th iteration, my program starts running into issues from having to deal with the enormous final string.  I would like to learn how I can reduce my complexity from what I think is O(N^2).

What alternative approaches are there for me to handle/concatenate very long strings in Python?  Is there a way for me to reduce the loading time/resources for doubling my strings?

Or is my current approach flawed and should I be approaching this issue from a different angle (one that I am so far unable to come up with an alternative for).

Edit: I have been told that this problem can be solved in O(1) - O(logn) time.

Comment: what are `start_index` and `end_index` used for? your description missed that.

Comment: My apologies, they are used for retrieving the substring from the final string.

Comment: My apologies, it was a typo.  I used starter() for a stopwatch to confirm that my brute force approach is exponential.

Comment: My apologies, I have accidentally mixed up parts from my different attempts.  I have rectified the typos.

Comment: Is this from from programming contest? If yes, can you provide a link? Are there any limits/constraints on the level or indices?

Comment: It is from a problem sheet.  The limits/constraints are 1 ≦ Level K ≦ 50, 1 ≦ start ≦ end ≦length of Level K String, and 1 ≦ end - start + 1 ≦ 100

Comment: A majority of time is consumed in the `.join`. If you just do `return strings_list[-1][start_index:end_index]`, it works fine for ~30 level. The generation from Martin's answer is obviously better.

Comment: Think of a tree where each node is `X{left_child}Y{right_child}Z`.  The string is then an in-order traversal of the tree.  You can calculate the length of a child tree from the formula given by Martin, so you know the index of X, Y, and Z. Only process a child node if it can overlap start_index to end_index..

Answer (score 8):

The length of the string at level \$ K \$ is \$ 3 (2^K -1) \$, which means that for \$ K = 50 \$ a string with \$ 3377699720527869 \$ characters is (recursively) built. That is about 3 [petabyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petabyte) (if you count one byte per character) and won't fit into the memory of your computer.

On the other hand, only a small portion of that complete string is actually needed, because of the constraint \$ 1 \le end - start + 1 \le 100 \$. And in many cases, that substring is already contained in the string given by a previous, smaller level.

Therefore I would prefer a recursive algorithm: Check the given start and end indices for the positions of "X", "Y" and "Z" from the current level, and recurse to the preceding level for the portions between those positions.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
def substring(level, start_index, end_index):
    # Indices of "X", "Z", "Y" at the current level:
    low = 1
    high = 3 * (2 ** level - 1)
    mid = (low + high) // 2

    result = ""
    while start_index <= end_index:
        if start_index == low:
            result += "X"
            start_index += 1
        elif start_index < mid:
            e = min(end_index, mid - 1)
            result += substring(level - 1, start_index - low, e - low)
            start_index += e - start_index + 1
        elif start_index == mid:
            result += "Y"
            start_index += 1
        elif start_index < high:
            e = min(end_index, high - 1)
            result += substring(level - 1, start_index - mid, e - mid)
            start_index += e - start_index + 1
        else:
            result += "Z"
            start_index += 1

    return result
```

It computes

```
substring(50, 3377699720527869-200, 3377699720527869-100)
```

within fractions of a second.

Further improvements are possible, e.g. by noting that the string on level K starts with K "X" characters and ends with K "Z" characters, or by handling the first level separately.

Answer (score 3):

### User input

First of all, it's important to provide a prompt string every time that you `input`. Currently, the user is presented with a blank console - they don't even have an indication that you're waiting for them to type something; for all they know the program is just hung. Instead, do something like

```
level = int(input('Please enter the level.'))
```

These `input` calls should be at the same (outer) level as your `print`, not in the `my_substring` routine. `my_substring` should accept integer parameters.

### String interpolation

Use an f-string; something like

```
strings[i] = f'X{strings[i - 1]}Y{strings[i - 1]Z'
```

### Naming

Generally instead of `strings_list`, you can just call it `strings` - the plural is a programmer hint that this is iterable, and you can add an actual `: List[str]` typehint to indicate that this is a string list.

### Algorithm

Instead of doing string concatenation inside the loop (and instead of an f-string), see if your runtime improves by doing list insertion. You will still do a `join`, just over expanded indexes.